# What are different ways to sort an encrypted column?

Tags: mysql, sorting, encryption

I have an AES encrypted column in MySQL and I want to sort it and paginate the results.

I am going through every row and adding it to an array. Then I sort the array. This becomes very slow with > 10K rows.

I was thinking about adding an extra column and adding the order from 0-#####, but the problem I see with this is that I have to update the ordering each time I insert a row in the middle.

I just wanted to brainstorm ideas if anyone has experience with this.

Thank you

Comment: Can you clarify, are you encrypting before inserting to database? Using mysql's ENCRYPT? How many rows do you expect?

Comment: Yes, I encrypted the data using mcrypt and stored the encrypted string. Right now, there is around 12K rows in the DB, but I want to list 25 per page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Schema

```
-- drop table encryptIt;
create table encryptIt
(   id int auto_increment primary key,
    ciphertext blob not null
);
```

encrypt from PHP into it as you are, or see [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16138757).

Now time to paginate out directly from mysql without PHP loops and sorting. Assuming you are giving the secret `your_key` to mysql. Assumes you can get a count which is elementary, and therefore know your page count (each page is 25).

```
SELECT id,CAST(AES_DECRYPT(ciphertext,'your_key') AS CHAR) AS cleartext
FROM encryptIt
order by cleartext
limit 0,25; -- start at first block of 25, bring back 25
-- limit 2,25; -- start at 3rd block of 25, bring back 25
```

Normal pagination applies using order by and limit.

Key management following best practices. A nebulous comment but I throw it out there.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably your encrypted rows don't have any natural sorting order. (That's part of the point of encrypting them.)

You could put an autoincrementing ID column on them and sort / paginate using that. You also could put an insertion timestamp on them.

But, if all you want is a stable sort order, so they come out in the same order each time you retrieve them, you can simply ORDER BY the encrypted values. If they're stored in a TEXT or binary large object (BLOB) column, you can order by that column's contents.

There's a setting called `max_sort_length` that controls the number of bytes considered by ORDER BY in large-object columns. Columns containing encrypted data probably can be sorted reliably by comparing just the first few dozen bytes. To do this give this command before doing the query with the ORDER BY.

```
SET max_sort_length 48
```

Read this for more information.  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/blob.html